# Url and alt from a image in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

```
$hover = get_post_meta( $cliente->ID, 'hover', true );
```

hover is a custom post field with ACF.
This custom post field has an image

$hover has an output:       string(3) "694"

How can i get the url and alt from this image?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the `wp_get_attachement` functions.

```
$hoverURL = wp_get_attachment_url( (int)$hover );
$hoverALT = get_post_meta( (int)$hover, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true );
```

The ALT content is saved as meta_data for the image attachment, so you're still using standard `get_post_meta()`.  I've also converted the `$hover` from a string to an integer using `(int)` because those WP functions require the `id` to be an integer.